# Ruby PDF Label Printer New Line Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Please be patient with me, this is the first time that I have ever messed with Ruby. Basically here is my issue. I have a huge site that is just needing a single thing modified however I'm running into issues.

I am trying to get a PDF output for a lapel printer to wrap down to the next line. Here is my code.

```
def print_labels
  quantity = params[:quantity].to_i
  hashed_label = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params[:label])
  p = InventoryItem.labels_pdf do |pdf|
  (1..quantity).each do |i|
    pdf.text("#{hashed_label['inventory_item_code']} #{hashed_label['label_description']} #{hashed_label['inventory_item_size']}", :style => :bold)
    pdf.text("#{hashed_label['ingredients']}", :size => 9, :font => :serif)
    #pdf.text(params[:label]);
    pdf.start_new_page if i < quantity
  end
end
send_data(p, :type => "application/x-pdf", :filename => "labels.pdf")
end
```

Here is the output in the PDF.

```
inventory_item_code label_description inventory_item_size
```

I am trying to get them to break between each item.

Comment: Is that the desired output or what it currently looks like?  You say you're "trying to get them to break", that's not very clear what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this using [Prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com)?  You should be able to put newlines in all you want:

```
pdf.text("Here is some\ntext with\nnewlines")
```

So, a newline after the `ingredients` would just be:

```
pdf.text("#{hashed_label['ingredients']}\n", :size => 9, :font => :serif)
```

Comment: This server is using Prawn 0.11.1.pre. I tried using "\n" however it doesn't seem to be working. The system it's self was built quite a few years ago and hasn't been touched since. Would there be some sort of caching built in to ruby or do I have to do some sort of recompile to get it to work?

Comment: Unless your server isn't reloading the classes, which can be fixed by just restarting it, there shouldn't be any "caching" like that.  Try adding static text to the label and see if it shows up, should show you if your changes are making it in.  Not sure how else to get a newline!

Comment: I did manage to get it working. However now due to Federal regulations I need to increase the margin. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Look for the `Prawn::Document.new` call (presumably in InventoryItem?), [and feed it new margins](http://rdoc.info/github/sandal/prawn/master/Prawn/Document#initialize-instance_method).